# Get View by ID from attributes in Custom View Class

Tags: android, layout

I want to get a view from his ID, from the attribute in the xml. I have tried with `getParent()` but it's return null.

**XML**

```
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:ntwldg="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/background_settings"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/revealView"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="TEST"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <com.dot.networkloading.NetworkLoading
            android:id="@+id/network_loading"
            ntwldg:text="Youtube"
            ntwldg:image="@drawable/ic_youtube"
            ntwldg:imageBackground="@drawable/ic_youtube"
            ntwldg:revealView="@id/revealView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The `attribute` `revealView` is referencing the `View` above.

**Code** - NetworkLoading (init())

```
        title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
        image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
        imageBackground = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageBackground);
        finishView = findViewById(R.id.revealView);

        String text = attributes.getString(R.styleable.network_loading_text);
        imageId = attributes.getResourceId(R.styleable.network_loading_image, 0);
        imageBackgroundId = attributes.getResourceId(R.styleable.network_loading_imageBackground, 0);

        finishView = ((View) getParent()).findViewById(attributes.getResourceId(R.styleable.network_loading_revealView, R.id.revealView));
```

Comment: It's a little unclear what you're asking, exactly. If you're just trying to get a reference to the `NetworkLoading` `View`, and `findViewById(R.id.revealView)` is successfully returning that `TextView`, then `findViewById(R.id.network_loading)` will give you that `NetworkLoading` `View`.

Comment: @MikeM. I want to get the R.id.revealView, from the NetworkLoading by passing this id from xml.

Comment: Oh, OK, I gotcha now. Where is that code, exactly? Is it in, or called from, `NetworkLoading`'s constructor?

Comment: @MikeM. He is in my post, the `finishView` is supposed to be the `TextView`

Comment: No, I mean, where does that code block get called in `NetworkLoading`? Are you calling it right from the constructor?

Comment: Oh, ok, I don't know how to do that, because I have see some method with `getParent()`. But he's return always `null`

Comment: OK, I'm still not exactly sure of your setup, but I'll post an answer of what I believe your problem is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you're trying to find your `revealView` too early. In the constructor, the `View` will not have yet been added to the layout it's in, so `getParent()` will return `null`. Keep the resource ID for the `revealView` as a field, get its value in the constructor, and then find the `View` in the `onAttachedToWindow()` method.

In the code you've posted, remove the last line - the last `finishView = ...` line - and instead save the resource ID to your field.

```
revealViewId = attributes.getResourceId(R.styleable.NetworkLoading_revealView, R.id.revealView);
```

Then find the `View` in the `onAttachedToWindow()` method instead.

```
@Override
protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();

    finishView = ((View) getParent()).findViewById(revealViewId);
    ...
}
```